Integrating BigBlueButton Webhook: Troubleshooting IncompleteRead
I'm trying to integrate a webhook with BigBlueButton (BBB) after successfully creating a meeting via the BBB API. However, when attempting to register the webhook, I encounter an IncompleteRead(0 bytes read) error.
Encountering this error on line:
response = requests.get(hook_create_url)

My Code:
def CreateBBBWebhook():
    # Define the parameter for webhook
    callback_url = 'yourserver.com'
    shared_secret = current_app.config['BBB_SHARED_SECRET']

    # Construct the query string
    query_string = f"callbackURL={callback_url}"

    # Calculate the checksum
    checksum_string = f"hooks/create{query_string}{shared_secret}"
    checksum = sha1(checksum_string.encode()).hexdigest()

   # Construct the final URL
   base_url = current_app.config['BIGBLUEBUTTON_PATH']
   hook_create_url = f"{base_url}hooks/create?{query_string}&checksum= 
   {checksum}"
   print("Hook create URL:", hook_create_url)

   # Make the request and handle exceptions
   try:
      response = requests.post(hook_create_url)
      print(response)
      return response
  except Exception as e:
     print("An unexpected error occurred:", e)
     return e

What I Tried:

Parameter Construction: I ensured that the parameters for both the meeting creation and the webhook registration were correctly constructed, including the checksum calculations.
URL Construction: I verified that the URLs were correctly formed and that the requests were properly sent to the BBB server.
Print Statements: Added print statements to check the URLs and parameters before making the requests.
Error Handling: Checked for any obvious mistakes in error handling or in the request logic.

Expected Outcome:
The expected outcome is that the webhook should be registered successfully, and the server should return a valid response indicating that the webhook has been created.
Actual Outcome:
I receive an IncompleteRead(0 bytes read) error when attempting to register the webhook.
Could anyone please help me in it.

Are you sure about the Python version? In any case, your Q lacks a [mcve] and the full backtrace of the error you get.

Python verion is 3.7.0. Also I'm not sure I have write the correct code? May be the implementation is wrong if you have any idea about bigbluebutton webhook registration then could you please tell me?

I don't even understand the problem yet, because your question is unclear. BTW: You can and should [edit] the question, in particular the "python-2.7" tag you applied.

I am getting the error "An unexpected error occurred: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)" while trying to integrate a webhook with BigBlueButton. I need help understanding how to use the webhook feature correctly. I have read the https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/development/webhooks/#hookscreate  and implemented the above code. However, I am encountering errors.
My goal is to implement the webhook to trigger events from BigBlueButton. Could you please help me understand if my code is implemented correctly? If it is, why am I encountering this error? If it is not correct, could you help me fix it?
